# Creating case in CRM dynamics from customer form submission

Tags: dynamics-crm, form-submit

I have a project that I'm working on and could use some help.

Basic idea is to create case in dynamics 365 CRM with data that customer submits trough form on my website. I did some research and found that i can use clickDimension or workflow. Butt this assignment is for my class and i need to do some coding. So my question would be where can i start or better what solution can I do with my code. Should I parse form submission to JSON and then pass it to CRM or just use CRM API and connect it with form. I'm open to any suggestions and if someone can help me and give me a few guidelines on what should I do. My coding knowledge is little limited so don't be hard on me if my first two solutions sounded stupid.

Thank you all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned your desired assignment is to do some coding,

I will do as follow

1. From submit on your website, Fire code (plugin,c#,java,python)
2. From your code, connect to Dynamics 365 (crm) webapi
3. Once you are connected you can easily create case in Dynmics 365 (crm)
4. If case creation is sucees or failure you can return

[Dataverse API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/overview)

[Applicaiton user for Dynamics 365 webapi](https://blog.dynamicscode.net/2018/08/07/accessing-dynamics-365-webapi-as-an-application-user-without-using-adal/)

[Applicaiton user for Dynamics 365 webapi](https://medium.com/capgemini-microsoft-team/dynamics-365-application-users-no-additional-license-required-and-no-limit-on-quantity-4bdc49f8ce2d)

[Applicaiton user for Dynamics 365 webapi](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/398392/api-calls-for-application-user-dynamics-365)

Comment: Thank you very much.

Now the question i didn't ask when i connect my form with API how can I get automated case creation in CRM, how do i code that or are there rules in CRM. I will do research about that but if you know it i would be very thankful.

Comment: If you dig deeper from Microsoft docs for data verse api you shall find examples as well. Just give yourself some time and you shall be able to achieve it.

Comment: could you please mark it as solved if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your website is WordPress based, you can use a plugin from [AlexaCRM](https://alexacrm.com/plugin/). Otherwise, if you can send an email from your website to CRM with required details, you can use the [Email to Case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-service/automatically-create-case-from-email) functionality to automatically create case from emails.